# Convert Outlook htmlrtf to html in perl

Tags: perl, outlook, rtf

I managed to extract the RTF part from an Outlook .msg using `Email::Outlook::Message`. Here's how it looks:

```
{\*\htmltag84 <b>}\htmlrtf {\b \htmlrtf0
{\*\htmltag148 <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;color:#002060;mso-fareast-language:EN-IN">}\htmlrtf {\lang1033 \htmlrtf0 FooBar
{\*\htmltag156 </span>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag92 </b>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0
```

When Outlooks sends an Internet Mail it converts the RTF to text/html:

```
<b><span style="font-size:12.0pt;color:#002060;mso-fareast-language:EN-IN">FooBar</span></b>
```

I'm trying to do the same using [RTF::HTML::Converter](https://metacpan.org/pod/RTF::HTML::Converter), but it strips all styling:

```
<b>FooBar</b>
```

Here's the script:

```
use strict;
use RTF::HTML::Converter;
my $object = RTF::HTML::Converter->new(
        output => \*STDOUT
);
local *RTF_FILE;
open RTF_FILE, "$ARGV[0]" or die $!;
$object->parse_stream( \*RTF_FILE );
```

I also tried the [unrtf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unrtf) tool. It also strips the styles:

```
<font face="Arial"><font size="3"><b>FooBar</b></font></font>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example it looks like the rtf contol words are redundant and wrapped by `\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0`. It might be sufficient for your usecase to strip them completely and use only the html tags. (This naive approach will probably break if you have more advanced formatting or embedded images etc.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;


while (my $line = <>){
    $line =~ s|\\htmlrtf.*?\\htmlrtf0||;
    $line =~ s|{\\\*\\htmltag\d+([^}]*)}|$1|;
    print $line;
}
```

```
perl test.pl test.rtf
 <b>
 <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;color:#002060;mso-fareast-language:EN-IN"> FooBar
 </span> 
 </b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse RTF to extract HTML, I am not aware of any libraries that do that.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile`, which returns [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object - you can read its `HTMLBody` property; it will extract HTML from RTF for you.